# Psexec runs batch file with no errors, but has no effect

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs a powershell script_1 that invokes another powershell script_2 with elevated credentials.

When I log into remote_server (Win Server 2012 R2, in WORKGROUP) and execute this batch script, it works perfectly.

When I log into host_server (Win Server 2012 R2, in WORKGROUP) and execute this batch script with psexec, it returns with an error code 0, but when I test whether this works, it is as if the powershell script_1 or script_2 never executed

On the host_server, I will run a cmd shell, Shift-right-click and select "Run as different user"

[image]

Then for username I type in "Administrator", and then the password.

Then I execute the following

```
D:\pstools\psexec.exe \\IP_of_remote_server -u username -p password -accepteula C:\share\enable.bat
```

And it executes with no error, and returns code of 0

**enable.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell.exe C:\share\eLEVATE.ps1
```

**eLEVATE.ps1**

```
$startInfo = $NULL
$process = $NULL


<#Previously created password file in C:\share\cred.txt, read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\share\cred.txt#>
$password = get-content C:\share\cred.txt | convertto-securestring

$startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
$startInfo.Arguments = "-noninteractive -windowstyle hidden -noprofile C:\share\remote_elevate.ps1 "

$startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
$startInfo.Username = "Administrator"
$startInfo.Domain = "WORKGROUP"
$startInfo.Password = $password 

$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $startInfo
$process.Start() | Out-Null
$userId = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
$process.WaitForExit()
```

**remote_elevate.ps1**

```
enable-psremoting -force
```

I have been trying to figure this out all morning. Thanks!

EDIT

I'm posting the exact screenshot of the errors I get when I enter

`d:\pstools\psexec.exe \\remote_IP -u Administrator -p password -accepteula cmd`

Then execute

`powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1`

[image]

Comment: What is the PowerShell `ExecutionPolicy` set to?

Comment: @aphoria - it is `RemoteSigned`

Comment: Have you tried just running CMD.exe with PSExec and seeing what it says when you try to run your `powershell.exe C:\share\eLEVATE.ps1` that way? Maybe you need `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass C:\share\eLEVATE.ps1` to bypass any execution policy that's blocking.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I tried `d:\pstools\psexec.exe \\remote_IP -u username -p password -accepteula cmd /c powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Try just `d:\pstools\psexec.exe \\remote_IP -u username -p password -accepteula cmd`. This opens a CMD prompt on the remote system. Then type in the `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1` command yourself and hit enter and see if it gives an error or anything. When done type Exit to close the remote cmd prompt and return to the local one.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I tried this, and once I type Exit to close, it returns 0, yet it still doesn't work

Comment: @TheMadTechnician and just for grinns I made the execution policy unrestricted and it still doesn't work

Comment: It's returning the 0 because CMD.EXE is running successfully and closing with no errors. It will not return any errors that PowerShell encounters.

Comment: When you follow @TheMadTechnician suggestion to just run CMD.EXE and then manually type and run your PowerShell command, what happens when you run `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1`? Any errors or messages?

Comment: @aphoria I RDP into remote_server, bring up CMD and type in `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1` There are no errors or messages and it works ... still baffled by why it's not working from host_server

Comment: That's not what @TheMadTechnician suggested. See his answer for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this as an answer since comments are not conveying what is needed with the limited formatting.

On the Host_server system bring up your command prompt as you described.

Enter the following command:

```
d:\pstools\psexec.exe \\remote_IP -u username -p password -accepteula cmd
```

The screen should display the following (Windows Version will be different since I ran this on Windows 7 Enterprise, and you will be doing it on Server 2012):

```
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

This is now a command prompt on the Remote_server. Anything executed from this prompt will not happen locally (host_server), but will happen on the remote_server computer. At this prompt enter the command:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1
```

Does that execute without errors? Does it do what it is supposed to?

Once you are finished with testing and are ready to close the command prompt on the remote_server system use the command:

```
exit
```

That will close the remote command prompt and will return you to your command prompt on the local computer (host_server).

PSExec will state a return code of 0, because CMD.exe closed normally. This does not reflect anything that PowerShell returned, only that cmd.exe on the remote system executed and closed normally.

Comment: I followed these steps on host_server. When I execute the powershell.exe ... there are no errors. When I type exit and enter, it says `cmd exited on remote_server with error code 0.` However, PSRemoting is still disabled on remote_server

Comment: Then is the user that you are using to execute PSExec an administrator on the Remote_Server computer?

Comment: username has admin rights on both host_server and remote_server. And Administrator has same password on both host_server and remote_server. However, when I was on host_server and executed `psexec.exe \\remote_IP -u Administrator -p password -accepteula cmd` and then executed `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass c:\share\eLEVATE.ps1`, I got several errors, i.e. `convertto-securestring : Key not valid for use in specified state.` and `Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The user name or password is incorrect"` ... but the encrypted password file is Administrator's password

Comment: Ok, so you do get errors. You said before that you did not get any errors, which didn't leave a lot to work with except account permissions issues. Ok, so the issue is that it can't convert the password string to a securestring. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the underlying process for that, so I'm probably not going to be able to help further at this point.

Comment: looking at `Get-Help ConvertTo-SecureString -full` you may need to setup a key when you encrypt the string for your password. In the file is it already encrypted, or is it in plain text?

Comment: This is good starting point, will create new question shortly